# In Depth-First Search Implementation, how to solve the neighbour value definition uncertainty

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to implement Depth-First Search algorithm in Python with this code

```
  graph = {
    '5': ['3','7'],
    '3': ['2','4'],
    '2': [],
    '4': ['8'],
    '7': ['8'],
    '8': []
}

visited = set()

def DFS(visited,graph,node):

    if node not in visited:
        print(node)
        visited.add(node)

        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            DFS(visited,graph,neighbour)


print("The result of the DFS is")
DFS(visited,graph,'5')
```

Yet, what I could not understand is how do we loop for graph[node] with neighbour. Where does the function take the value of this variable from?

Comment: The code is meant to print each node in dfs order?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, as indicated in [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp), `for` loops work like iterator methods. This means that the loop variable (in your code this is `neighbour`) systematically takes on each value in the iterator (in your code this is the list `graph[node]`). Importantly, you don't need to define this loop variable anywhere else -  the `for` loop *is* the definition.

For example, take `node = '5'` (and thus `graph[node] = ['3', '7']`), and consider the following loop:

```
for neighbour in graph[node]:
    print(neighbour)
```

This gives the output

```
> 3
> 7
```

In the first pass through the loop, `neighbour` takes on the first value in the list `graph[node]`. In the second pass, it takes on the second value of `graph[node]` and so on.

You may also find the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) on `for` loops helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I predicted that it could be related to the graph itself yet I wanted to be sure. Your answer is really helpful. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome @IMysth. If you feel that your question has been completely answered, can I ask that you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) you found most helpful. This indicates to other users that your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For a tree of this structure (mixture of `list` and `dict`) like the one you provided:

```
graph = {
    '5': ['3','7'],
    '3': ['2','4'],
    '2': [],
    '4': ['8'],
    '7': ['8'],
    '8': []
}
```

You can do DFS like this:

```
def dfs(node):
    if node is [] or node is {}:
        return
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        for key, val in node.items():
            print(key)
            dfs(val)
    elif isinstance(node, list):
        for elem in node:
            dfs(elem)
    else:
        print(node)
```

```
dfs(graph)
```

prints

```
5
3
7
3
2
4
2
4
8
7
8
8
```